# Best practice to retrieve error message from database

Tags: c#, database, oracle11g

We have list of error messages in our database table and we fetch these error messages from table when we face some business validation error.
for e.g. If in c# code we find that the calculated risk % is more then allowed value, when use below code

```
string sError = GetErrorText(6610);  // get error message from application cache
DisplayErrorPopup(sError ); // load a popup to display error to user.
```

Now we have found that there are scenarios where we have to validate stuff few rules from stored Procedure. for e.g. "No active supervisor for worker."

**My question is how should we handle this scenario when validation happens in database?** 
A. Should we return error text "No active supervisor for worker." as out param of SP  and pass it to DisplayErrorPopup
**OR**
B. Return the error id (which is present in table) and then use GetErrorText(834) and then pass the text to DisplayErrorPopup;

**My concerns are** 

1. Is there any industry standard to best practice to handle error messages and texts.
2. Is there any drawback of returning string / varchar from database when we have option of returning number.

Please guide me on this.

Comment: If the only thing you need to do is display the error message then I think it is better to return the string directly via an output parameter of the stored procedure. If you return an ID then you need another call to get the text out of the database.

Comment: Try this one http://arun-ts.blogspot.in/2007/07/raiserror-in-sql-server-catch-in-c.html

Comment: Hi @Steve : that is the trick here. we dont have to hit the DB again, as all error messages are loaded into Application variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest throwing (raising) a custom error in SQL (you could select the text out of a table if you like) and letting your application catch that error. This will allow you to let your application decide how to handle different errors based on how critical they are.

```
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = timeout;
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conn.Open();
            object result = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();

            return result;
        }
```

Running the above inside of a try catch block will allow you to handle your errors more elegantly inside of your C# app

Answer (score 0):

Both your options are equally correct.You can either return an error text from database, or return some error code and display error message based on that code in your application.

Also, try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET) atricle from **codeproject** as it has both industry standard and best practice to handle error messages and texts explained in detail.